# Can you group different shades/tints of a color into a group / find the base color

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, rgb

Is there a way to find the base color starting from a tint/shade of that color or group variations of a color together?

Eg: #9c2b2b / RGB (156,43,43) is a shade of red
and #2354c4 / RGB (132,162,232) is a tint of blue

But giving this tow colors for example is there a way to determine in Python that this is variation of red (#FF0000 rgb(255, 0, 0)) or blue (#0000FF rgb(0, 0, 255))

I know how to and I found online a lot of tutorials and answer on how to do gradients by taking a base color and multiplying or subtracting.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, there is a way. One way would be to say that in #9c2b2b the R channel has the largest value and therefore it's a variation of red, and in #2354c4 the B channel has the largest value and therefore it's a variation of blue.

Comment: It's possible, but your question needs more focus... **1.** Define a distance function between two colors. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) there are multiple options (the distance function gets two colors and returns a number that defines the difference). **2.** Search for the base color with the minimum distance to the "starting color".

Comment: To reduce confusion, we use (colour management) the following notation: *colour* defines a specific sensation on brain, and *hue* is the chromaticity (so a family of shades/tints). So I think you are just looking the hue (usually defined as angle). HCL, HSL, HSV colour space gives you the hue, so just convert colour space. Note: it fails for some unsaturated colours, like white, black, grey, brown (a shade of orange?) (and e.v. pink if you do not consider pink a tint of red). But with L/V part you can get it.